# AWS Glue job create_dynamic_frame_from_options() opening a specific file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

If one uses create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog(), you supply the database name and table name, e.g. created from a Glue crawler, which effectively names a specific input file.  I want to be able to do the same (name a specific input file) *without* the crawler and database.

I've tried using create_dynamic_frame_from_options(), but the "path" connection option doesn't allow me to name the file, apparently.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to read multiple files from a specific s3 path and want the filename in your dataframe. You can achieve this by using spark session and reading it as pyspark dataframe

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session

path = 's3://bucket/folder'
df = spark.read.csv(path)
df = df.withColumn('FileName', input_file_name())
```